# numpy read .csv with complex number

Tags: python, csv, file-io, numpy, complex-numbers

stackoverflow,

I have a matrix containing complex numbers (ex. -2.2982235934153075E-11+2.1179547211742553E-9i) that I need to import to a numpy array. I've been using `genfromtext(file)` to parse all my other, real values, but I'm getting a `nan` for all complex values. Any ideas?

```
self.raw = (genfromtxt(self.loc, delimiter=',', skip_header=9, dtype=float))
[m,n] = shape(self.raw)
data = zeros((m, n-3))
data[:, :] = self.raw[:, 3::]
```

returns:

```
data = array([nan, nan, nan, ...])
```

Comment: paste some code that you used and paste an exemplary input (preferably, part of the input file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ended up having to do this was to first `replace('i', 'j')` for all cells in the original .csv file and save the new, corrected file. Afterwards, reading the .csv with `dtype=str` caused errors in subsequent calculations, but it turns out you can parse the .csv with `dtype=complex128`, which solved all my problems. Thanks for the help on the conversion @Saullo-Castro

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.genfromtxt(filename, converters={0: lambda x: x.replace('i','j')},
                  dtype=str)
a = np.complex_(a)
```

Note that the `converters` parameter was required because your text file is using `i` to denote the imaginary part.

It may be easier to convert your text file externally to replace all the `i` by `j`, avoiding a complicated `converters` argument in case you have many columns.

If your textfile with imaginary numbers had the format:

```
 (-2.298223593415307508e-11+2.117954721174255306e-09j)
 (-2.298223593415307508e-11+2.117954721174255306e-09j)
 (-2.298223593415307508e-11+2.117954721174255306e-09j)
 (-2.298223593415307508e-11+2.117954721174255306e-09j)
 (-2.298223593415307508e-11+2.117954721174255306e-09j)
 (-2.298223593415307508e-11+2.117954721174255306e-09j)
 (-2.298223593415307508e-11+2.117954721174255306e-09j)
```

Where you could read using only:

```
a = np.loadtxt(filename).view(complex)
```

for example...

Comment: This works for a single column.  It appears the data is suppose to be multi-column.  I would probably externally convert the 'i'->'j' in the data file, perhaps using sed, awk, or even perl!, then read  in the converted file using dtype=np.complex

Comment: If you can convert it externally you don't need to use the `converters` argument for this case...

Comment: Right, and you wouldn't have to worry about the actual number of columns in the file.  It isn't entirely clear what the constraints from the OP are.

Comment: OP here, python seems to be reading the columns of the .csv ([m,n] =[2500, 400]) as strings.

Edit: 'Python' <--- "Excel'

Comment: @1ifbyLAN2ifbyC did you mean Python? does your real file has more than one column? in this case I may need to update the answer...

Comment: it seems like the best course of action is to import the .csv as a string, then parse/replace 'i' with 'j', and finally import my new list (?) into a numpy array? This is assuming numpy can recongnize complex numbers that take the form XXX + XXXj

Comment: @1ifbyLAN2ifbyC yes... if the file is written like `(x + yj)`, including the brackets, it will easily read using `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt`, as examplified in the answer...

Comment: @SaulloG.P.Castro I'm getting a ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(731.155153+0.000000j)' on a .txt with 12731 by 12731 matrix of complex numbers i.e. (731.155153+0.000000j), when I simply read the .txt file by  a = np.loadtxt(filename).view(complex)

Comment: @JuneWang have you tried the other solution with genfromtxt?

Answer (score 1):

The following might be an option to obtain a **NumPy array** from **multi-column** **complex-numbered .csv file**:

Say we have a `file.csv` containing two rows and three columns of complex numbers:

```
-0.00034467+0.j,         0.00493246+0.j,         0.00365753-0.00361799j
-0.00782533-0.00081274j,-0.00402968+0.01065282j,-0.01345174+0.00464461j
```

The following will yield a NumPy array:

```
filename = 'file.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=",", header=None)
data = data.applymap(lambda s: np.complex(s.replace('i', 'j'))).values
```

Checking if `data` is a NumPy array:

```
>> type(data)
numpy.ndarray
```

PS: The answer is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50331578/3393574).

Answer (score -1):

Import the csv file as an array of strings with `genfromtxt(...)` with `dtype='str'`. Then you can manipulate each entry with `np.vectorize(...)`.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

# import data as an array of strings using the dtype
temp = genfromtxt('matlab_sim_Z.csv', delimiter=',',dtype='str')

# perform elementwise conversion to complex numpers
mapping = np.vectorize(lambda t:complex(t.replace('i','j')))
data = mapping(temp)
```

In a single line:

```
data = np.vectorize(lambda t:complex(t.replace('i','j'))) (genfromtxt('matlab_sim_Z.csv', delimiter=',',dtype='str'))
```