# python pandas complex number

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas which very efficiently sorts/filters the data they way I need.

This code worked fine, until I changed the last column to a complex number; now I get an error.

> return self._cython_agg_general('mean') raise DataError('No numeric
>   types to aggregate') pandas.core.groupby.DataError: No numeric types
>   to aggregate

The error refers to my eighth column (with the complex numbers) since I want the mean value
I cannot find a way to convert the object to a complex number (from what I understand pandas now support complex numbers).

This is the code I use.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('final.dat', sep=",", header=None)
df.columns=['X.1', 'X.2', 'X.3', 'X.4','X.5', 'X.6', 'X.7', 'X.8']
df1 = df.groupby(["X.1","X.2","X.5"])["X.8"].mean().reset_index()
```

After that I get the error described above.

When I read my file, this is the df output.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 21266 entries, 0 to 21265
Data columns (total 8 columns):
X.1    21266  non-null values
X.2    21266  non-null values
X.3    21266  non-null values
X.4    21266  non-null values
X.5    21266  non-null values
X.6    21266  non-null values
X.7    21266  non-null values
X.8    21266  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4), int64(3), object(1)
```

This is a small sample of the [input file](http://pastebin.com/V45UwRQy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parse doesn't support reading of complex directly, so do the following transform.

```
In [37]: df['X.8'] = df['X.8'].str.replace('i','j').apply(lambda x: np.complex(x))

In [38]: df
Out[38]: 
          X.1         X.2  X.3   X.4    X.5  X.6  X.7                X.8
0   564991.15  7371277.89    0     1   1530  0.1    2   (92.289+151.96j)
1   564991.15  7371277.89    0     1   8250  0.1    2   (104.22-43.299j)
2   564991.15  7371277.89    0     1  20370  0.1    2    (78.76-113.52j)
3   564991.15  7371277.89    0     1  33030  0.1    2    (27.141-154.1j)
4   564991.15  7371277.89    0     1  47970  0.1    2     (-30.012-175j)
5   564991.15  7371277.89    0     1  63090  0.1    2  (-118.52-342.43j)
6   564991.15  7371277.89    0     1  93090  0.1    2  (-321.02-1541.5j)
7   564991.15  7371277.89    0     2   1530  0.1    2   (118.73+154.05j)
8   564991.15  7371277.89    0     2   8250  0.1    2   (122.13-45.571j)
9   564991.15  7371277.89    0     2  20370  0.1    2   (93.014-116.03j)
10  564991.15  7371277.89    0     2  33030  0.1    2    (38.56-155.08j)
11  564991.15  7371277.89    0     2  47970  0.1    2  (-20.653-173.83j)
12  564991.15  7371277.89    0     2  63090  0.1    2  (-118.41-340.58j)
13  564991.15  7371277.89    0     2  93090  0.1    2    (-378.71-1554j)
14  564990.35  7371279.17    0  1785   1530  0.1    2   (-15.441+118.3j)
15  564990.35  7371279.17    0  1785   8250  0.1    2  (-7.1735-76.487j)
16  564990.35  7371279.17    0  1785  20370  0.1    2  (-33.847-145.99j)
17  564990.35  7371279.17    0  1785  33030  0.1    2  (-86.035-185.46j)
18  564990.35  7371279.17    0  1785  47970  0.1    2  (-143.37-205.23j)
19  564990.35  7371279.17    0  1785  63090  0.1    2  (-234.67-370.43j)
20  564990.35  7371279.17    0  1785  93090  0.1    2  (-458.69-1561.4j)
21  564990.36  7371279.17    0  1786   1530  0.1    2    (36.129+128.4j)
22  564990.36  7371279.17    0  1786   8250  0.1    2   (39.406-69.607j)
23  564990.36  7371279.17    0  1786  20370  0.1    2   (10.495-139.48j)
24  564990.36  7371279.17    0  1786  33030  0.1    2  (-43.535-178.19j)
25  564990.36  7371279.17    0  1786  47970  0.1    2  (-102.28-196.76j)
26  564990.36  7371279.17    0  1786  63090  0.1    2   (-199.32-362.1j)
27  564990.36  7371279.17    0  1786  93090  0.1    2  (-458.09-1565.6j)

In [39]: df.dtypes
Out[39]: 
X.1       float64
X.2       float64
X.3       float64
X.4         int64
X.5         int64
X.6       float64
X.7         int64
X.8    complex128
dtype: object

In [40]: df1 = df.groupby(["X.1","X.2","X.5"])["X.8"].mean().reset_index()

In [41]:  df.groupby(["X.1","X.2","X.5"])["X.8"].mean().reset_index()
Out[41]: 
          X.1         X.2    X.5                  X.8
0   564990.35  7371279.17   1530     (-15.441+118.3j)
1   564990.35  7371279.17   8250    (-7.1735-76.487j)
2   564990.35  7371279.17  20370    (-33.847-145.99j)
3   564990.35  7371279.17  33030    (-86.035-185.46j)
4   564990.35  7371279.17  47970    (-143.37-205.23j)
5   564990.35  7371279.17  63090    (-234.67-370.43j)
6   564990.35  7371279.17  93090    (-458.69-1561.4j)
7   564990.36  7371279.17   1530      (36.129+128.4j)
8   564990.36  7371279.17   8250     (39.406-69.607j)
9   564990.36  7371279.17  20370     (10.495-139.48j)
10  564990.36  7371279.17  33030    (-43.535-178.19j)
11  564990.36  7371279.17  47970    (-102.28-196.76j)
12  564990.36  7371279.17  63090     (-199.32-362.1j)
13  564990.36  7371279.17  93090    (-458.09-1565.6j)
14  564991.15  7371277.89   1530  (105.5095+153.005j)
15  564991.15  7371277.89   8250    (113.175-44.435j)
16  564991.15  7371277.89  20370    (85.887-114.775j)
17  564991.15  7371277.89  33030    (32.8505-154.59j)
18  564991.15  7371277.89  47970  (-25.3325-174.415j)
19  564991.15  7371277.89  63090  (-118.465-341.505j)
20  564991.15  7371277.89  93090  (-349.865-1547.75j)
```

Comment: thanks Jeff, this seems to work - I get an error message (that the imaginary part is discarded) but the values appear right!

Comment: really, that is weird. also numpy uses j for complex part, FYI

Comment: maybe my versions are different? running exactly the same as above here is the error message: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/nanops.py:549: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  x = float(x)

Comment: numpy version? (I am using 1.7.1)

Comment: same here - numpy 1.7.1 (I just also updated to pandas 12, the latest version, but same thing)

Comment: @Dimitris it seems like it's a bug in the pandas library. [Relevant line](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/nanops.py#L549) - this should probably check also if it's a complex number? Jeff? `elif not (com.is_float(x) or com.is_integer(x) or com.is_complex(x))`

Comment: Tested it. That's the problem.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez can you file a report? PR would be wecome too!

Comment: I'll do it, I'm waiting the tests to pass don't want to break something else :)

Comment: @ViktorKerkez so, I need to update the line in my pandas library and check if it works? sorry, but I am really not experienced..

Comment: @ViktorKerkez yes, it appears to work now - I run two files with no problem!!!! thanks!!!!!!

Comment: So - where is this Series.str functionality documented? I can't find it at all, but it shows up in a number of SO posts.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can parse it directly as a complex number by passing in a converter for that column when you read in the data:

```
pd.read_csv('final.dat', header=None,
            names=['X.1', 'X.2', 'X.3', 'X.4','X.5', 'X.6', 'X.7', 'X.8'],
            converters={'X.8': lambda s: np.complex(s.replace('i', 'j'))})
```

Comment: thanks, that looks good too, but I still get the same error as above (see my comment to Jeff)

Comment: nice approach for the converters.  I had seen reference to direct support for `complex numbers` somewhere else but it did not seem to work

Answer (score 2):

For converting all columns, try `pd.applymap(lambda s: np.complex(s.replace('i', 'j')))`

Comment: With the help of this answer, a minimal example can be found [hereat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57611919/3393574)

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing the lambda but was getting a error:

> ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string

I found out I had to eliminate the spaces as well as change the 'i' character to 'j'
Here's my code:

```
for tits in df.columns:
    if df[tits].dtypes =='O':
        df[tits] = df[tits].str.replace('i','j')
        df[tits] = df[tits].str.replace(' ','')
        df[tits] = df[tits].apply(lambda x: np.complex(x))
print(df[df.columns[1]])
print(df.dtypes)
```