# remove parentheses from complex numbers - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, complex-numbers

As a follow up to this post [python pandas complex number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919699/python-pandas-complex-number) and now that complex works fine with pandas, I want to save the complex numbers but without the parentheses - 
when I use the following command the last column (complex number) is printed inside parentheses
EDIT: here is the full code, to read the data file (sample [here](http://pastebin.com/V45UwRQy))

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('final.dat', sep=",", header=None)
df.columns=['X.1', 'X.2', 'X.3', 'X.4','X.5', 'X.6', 'X.7', 'X.8']
df['X.8'] = df['X.8'].str.replace('i','j').apply(lambda x: np.complex(x))
df1 = df.groupby(["X.1","X.2","X.5"])["X.8"].mean().reset_index()
df1['X.3'] = df["X.3"] #add extra columns
df1['X.4']=df["X.4"]
df1['X.6']=df["X.6"]
df1['X.7']=df["X.7"]
sorted_data = df1.reindex_axis(sorted(df1.columns), axis=1)
sorted_data.to_csv = ('final_sorted.dat', sep=',', header = False)
```

all works well, but the in the output csv file the complex are inside parentheses - and I cannot use them this way, so I want to remove them

Comment: Please include everything that is relevant to this question.

Comment: @flornquake updated per your comment - let me know if additional info is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prob could have better support for reading/writing complex, but ATM this will work.

```
In [25]: df = DataFrame([[1+2j],[2-1j]],columns=list('A'))

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
        A
0  (1+2j)
1  (2-1j)

In [27]: df['A'] = df['A'].apply(str).str.replace('\(|\)','')

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
      A
0  1+2j
1  2-1j

In [29]: df.to_csv('test.csv')

In [30]: !cat test.csv
,A
0,1+2j
1,2-1j
```