# Convert list of strings to numpy array of floats

Tags: arrays, string, list, numpy, casting

Assume I have a list of strings and I want to convert it to the numpy array. For example I have

```
A=A=['[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]','[8 9 10 11 12 13 14]']
print(A)
['[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]', '[8 9 10 11 12 13 14]']
```

I want my output to be like the following : a matrix of 2 by 7

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7;8 9 10 11 12 13 14]
```

What I have tried thus far is the following:

```
m=len(A)
M=[]
for ii in range(m):
    temp=A[ii]
    temp=temp.strip('[')
    temp=temp.strip(']')
    M.append(temp)
print(np.asarray(M))
```

however my output is the following:

```
['1 2 3 4 5 6 7' '8 9 10 11 12 13 14']
```

Can anyone help me to correctly remove the left and right brackets and convert the result to the matrix of floats.

Comment: Where did your strings come from?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/56627106/901925

Comment: @StephenRauch from reading a csv file in python using panda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go the direct route.  Remove the brackets, split on the spaces and convert to float before sending the result to numpy.array:

```
np.array([[float(i) for i in j[1:-1].split()] for j in A])
```

#### Test Code:

```
import numpy as np
A = ['[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]','[8 9 10 11 12 13 14]']
print(np.array([[float(i) for i in j[1:-1].split()] for j in A]))
```

#### Results:

```
[[  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.]
 [  8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.]]
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code does ? what would be the unwrapped version of your code?

Comment: I did explain.  Remove the brackets, split on the spaces and convert to float.  Other than that, go study [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: @user59419, I think it would be a good Python exercise for you to translate the list comprehension to a loop (two loops actually).  There's a straight forward mapping between append loops as you started with and list comprehensions.