# Numpy read complex numbers from text file

Tags: python, numpy

I have used numpy to save a matrix of complex numbers. The output file looks like that:

```
(1.100412357301083777e-02+1.471303433818593742e-02j)     (1.511426586599529109e-02+-2.516143258497194335e-03j)   
(1.084202636262432407e-02+1.438252996657629623e-02j)     (1.447620213198375083e-02+4.471111098343749646e-03j)
```

Now, I tried reading it in using numpy `data = np.loadtxt('PsiPfree1.out', delimiter='\t', dtype=np.complex128)`, but I get the following error:

```
items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]  
ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string`
```

Any ideas how I could get this to work?

Edit: I now also tried without the parenthesis making the matrix look like this:

```
1.100412357301083777e-02+1.471303433818593742e-02j  1.511426586599529109e-02+-2.516143258497194335e-03j
1.084202636262432407e-02+1.438252996657629623e-02j  1.447620213198375083e-02+4.471111098343749646e-03j
```

This results in the same issue.

Comment: That's probably cause of the parentheses. Get rid of those first

Comment: I tried by replacing with spaces. Exactly the same error.

Comment: Don't use any spaces/parentheses/commas/squiggly lines. The delimiter between your values should be the string you're specifying as the delimiter, and that string only.

Comment: Ok, I have tried that and posted the modified matrix above. Still no luck.

Comment: Re: your edit, did you change the specified delimiter string to two spaces once you started using spaces?

Comment: In my textfile it is tab delimited. I do not know why it here appears to be spaces.

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the second column, first row. Is the `+-` intentional?

Comment: This is how the file looked after I saved the matrix using `np.savetxt('PsiPges.out',PsiPges , delimiter='\t') `.

Comment: If I change that, however, it works. That means my propblem is the saving part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think I was wrong; you might have a negative complex part in that number, which is perfectly valid. You might try the approach in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18280813/1726343

Comment: Can you post your comment as answer, then I could accept it as the correct answer. Thanks for your time. After changing the +- to - it worked with the initial command for loading the matrix.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012484/how-to-save-a-complex-matrix-in-a-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the numpy savetxt function `np.savetxt('PsiPges.out',PsiPges , delimiter='\t')` I used exports the data matrix, but for all negative imaginary parts it writes `+-` (see matrix posted above). If this is replaced by `-` only, the loadtxt function works correctly.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought you were fixing the problem by simply removing the minus, which would have given you wrong values.

Comment: ;) No. Thank you for your time! I wouöld never have found that.